# OpenAL. alcGetIntegerv returns samples = 0 for iPad

Tags: ipad, audio-streaming, openal

Audio capturing with OpenAL works OK for iPhone.
When I run the same application for iPad, *alcGetIntegerv* returns *samples = 0*. I've checked for errors both with *alcGetError* and *alGetError* methods after *alcCaptureOpenDevice*, *alcCaptureStart* and *alcGetIntegerv*, there are no any errors. Capture device is not null after *alcCaptureOpenDevice*. Any ideas why this doesn't work for iPad?